# Shopware 6 Admin CMS Mapping field missing possible fields from Entity Extension

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We created an entity extension in the regular way https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities#entity-extension-vs.-custom-fields

Our entity extension extends the Category Entity and creates a ManyToOne Association to a custom entity

**Entity Extension:**

```
class CategoryWeingutseitenExtension extends EntityExtension
{

    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new OneToOneAssociationField('weingutseite', 'id', 'category_id', CategoryWeingutseitenExtensionDefinition::class, true)
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
       return CategoryDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

**Entity Extension Definition:**

```
class CategoryWeingutseitenExtensionDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'airtable_category_weingutseiten_extension';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    public function getEntityClass(): string
    {
        return CategoryWeingutseitenExtensionEntity::class;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id','id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
            (new FkField('category_id', 'categoryId', CategoryDefinition::class)),
            (new FkField('weingutseiten_id', 'weingutseitenId', WeingutseitenDefinition::class)),

            new OneToOneAssociationField('category', 'category_id', 'id', CategoryDefinition::class, false),
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('weingutseite', 'weingutseiten_id', WeingutseitenDefinition::class, 'id', true)
        ]);
    }
}
```

We managed to extend the regular category admin UI to assign this custom entity to a category. This works fine and vue auto loads the data in the category.extension.* like expected

[image]

As you can see, our associated model contains some media relations which we want to use in the category CMS elements.

Unfortunately only category.media appears in the CMS data mapping:

[image]

It seems like the sw-cms/service/cms.service.js receives the entity definition but without any extension field:

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/v6.4.15.1/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/service/cms.service.js#L155

[image]

How can I manage to get the extension data into that entity definition as a property to use it in the cms-mapping-field?

Answer (score 3):

That is currently not supported, best way to achieve that would be to create a PR yourself adding support for extensions there.

Otherwise please create a ticket at the [official issue tracker](https://issues.shopware.com), so support for that may be added by shopware.

Comment: I created a pull request for that https://github.com/shopware/platform/pull/2735